# Prelink warning in output of rpm -Va

Tags: rhel, rpm

I have run the following as root on a RHEL 4 box to get a list of the modified files:

```
rpm -Va
```

The output includes lines such as:

```
prelink: /tmp/#prelink#.60m2Jq: Recorded 2 dependencies, now seeing -1

S.?.....    /usr/bin/gencat
prelink: /tmp/#prelink#.2izAsr: Recorded 2 dependencies, now seeing -1

S.?.....    /usr/bin/getconf
prelink: /tmp/#prelink#.QIPLxn: Recorded 2 dependencies, now seeing -1

S.?.....    /usr/bin/getent
```

Are the prelink warnings anything to worry about?

Secondly, the question mark in the MD5 sum column means that the value could not be calculated. Any theories as to why? I can do `md5sum filename` without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would backup and  reinstall (`--force`) the affected packages, just to be on the safe side. My reading of the diagnostic is that those binaries are statically linked (but were not when `prelink` last ran). If that's true (try `ldd getent`) that's a strong hint of a cracked machine.

Comment: I concur with AlienLifeForm's analysis. On the surface this sounds like the binaries were altered either accidentally or intentionally.